# Check if if one dataframe string is present in second dataframe (even as a substring) string at the same position

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count in two different dataframes, how many strings from the first are contained in the second. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame([["hello, world", "hello, world"]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", "hello"]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

If I choose, `idx_row = 0`, I would expect a `sum` of 2 since the word `"hello"` is contained for both columns `'A'` and `'B'` in the second dataframe `"hello, world"`.

```
idx_row = 0    
np.sum(np.where(df_2.iloc[idx_row,:] in df_1[idx_row, :], 1, 0))
TypeError: '(0, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Comment: so you are trying to see if one dataframe string is present in second dataframe (even as a substring) string at the same position?

Comment: What would be the sum if it was `['hello', 'yellow']`?

Comment: exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with join values by `|` for regex `or`, it means tested all values are tested for `hello` or `hello`:

```
idx_row = 0  

a = df_1.iloc[idx_row, :].str.count('|'.join(df_2.iloc[idx_row,:])).sum()
print (a)
2
```

Old answer for test each values per rows:

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join first rows and then test values in `apply` by `in`, last sum `True`s by `sum`:

```
idx_row = 0  

a = (pd.concat([df_2.iloc[idx_row,:],  df_1.iloc[idx_row, :]], axis=1, keys=('a','b'))
       .apply(lambda x: x.a in x.b, axis=1)
       .sum())
print (a)
2
```

If need test all rows (matching index, columns values):

```
s = (pd.concat([df_2, df_1], axis=1, keys=('a','b'))
       .stack()
       .apply(lambda x: x.a in x.b, axis=1)
       .sum(level=0))
print (s)
0    2
1    2
2    2
dtype: int64
```